# How can one tell the version of React running at runtime in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to know the runtime version of React in the browser?

Comment: Open your debugger tools, look at the source files, find the javascript file for React, and open it.  Libraries usually have their versions printed at the top, even if they're minified.  Sometimes, you can also identify the version by the file name.

Comment: In your Chrome console with React Developer Tools, `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.values().next()["value"]["version"]`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`React.version` is what you are looking for.

It is undocumented though (as far as I know) so it may not be a stable feature (i.e. though unlikely, it may disappear or change in future releases).

**Example with `React` imported as a script**

```js
const REACT_VERSION = React.version;

let root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <div>React version: {REACT_VERSION}</div>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Example with `React` imported as a module**

```
import { version } from 'react';

console.log(version);
```

Obviously, if you import `React` as a module, it won't be in the global scope. The above code is intended to be bundled with the rest of your app, e.g. using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org). It will virtually never work if used in a browser's console (it is using bare imports).

This second approach is the recommended one. Most websites will use it. [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) does this (it's using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) behind the scene). In this case, `React` is encapsulated and is generally not accessible at all outside the bundle (e.g. in a browser's console).

Comment: I was able to console.log(React.version) at the entry point of my program to get the version

Comment: @gotofritz No? I just tested with React 16.0.0 and it was still working. What react version are you using? How do you import it?

Comment: Maybe it depends on how the app is packaged. With create-react-app there is no global React object.

Comment: No. There is no React global if you are importing react as a module. In that case, you need to import the module first and fetch the `version` property of the module.

Comment: This doesn't work on sites that use ReactJS and you are trying to find the version. I've tried this on several sites and I keep getting the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

Comment: @pixel67 What is your case?

Comment: @QuentinRoy, I used your snippet in the console of sites using ReactJS

Comment: It is no surprise it does not work if you try it as is on production websites. The second snippet will virtually never work when used directly in the browser (it is using nodeJS `require` and is supposed to be transpiled). The first might, but many (not to say most) websites using react will encapsulate it so that is not available from the global scope. I.e., you just cannot access it at all if you are not the developer yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying, I wish there was a way to access the version through the window using `window.React.VERSION` or something like that but using `Webpack` and the I'm assuming not having it Global is the whole point?

Comment: If you are using webpack you can always inject it yourself if you really need to access it globally (e.g. by adding `window.React = require('react');` somewhere in your source code)..

Comment: Works on v.  15.6.2.

Comment: anyway to check ReactDOM version

Comment: Working in 17.0.2

Comment: `render()` is deprecated in React 18, you should now use `createRoot()`: `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';ReactDOM.createRoot()`

Answer (score 160):

From the command line:

```sh
npm view react version
npm view react-native version
```

Comment: This is wrong, `npm view` returns latest version from npm registery, not version in use. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-view

Comment: you should run this command in your present working directory which is supposed to be your reactjs app folder.

Comment: This is not the runtime version from the browser, asked in the question. The correct answer is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60280185/358532

Answer (score 61):

With the React Devtools installed you can run this from the browser console:

```
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.forEach(r => console.log(`${r.rendererPackageName}: ${r.version}`))
```

Which outputs something like:

```
react-dom: 16.12.0
```

Comment: This seems to be the only actually working solution for finding out React version used on a website.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution as it doesn't require tinkering with the source files, or the website using require().
It probably *should* be the accepted answer as it does what the OP was asking

Answer (score 18):

If you have the React DevTools extension enabled, you can execute this in the console:
`window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.get(1).version`

Here's the output if I execute it on my website in production (nikolovlazar.com)
[image: Check React version in production]

Comment: Really useful. This can be used to check React version without making changes to code.

Answer (score 16):

Open Chrome Dev Tools or equivalent and run `require('React').version` in the console.

That works on websites like Facebook as well to find out what version they are using.

Comment: Tried it...doesn't work with my app..running version react-dom v16.

Comment: In Firefox: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Comment: That's because the site you're testing it on does not use requirejs. @JonSchneider

Comment: @WillHoskings: Interesting observation.  Is there any way to get around it, or are we stuck?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Unless React pollutes the global scope with the "React" global,  I don't know.

Comment: this won't wort on most of the borwsers!, but you can always run `node` in your  terminal and then run the snipet you shared above `require('react').version. this worked fine for me

Answer (score 16):

It is not certain that any global ECMAScript variables have been exported and html/css does not necessarily indicate React. So look in the .js.

**Method 1: Look in ECMAScript:**

The version number is exported by both modules **react-dom** and **react** but those names are often removed by bundling and the version hidden inside an execution context that cannot be accessed. A clever break point may reveal the value directly, or you can search the ECMAScript:

1. Load the Web page (you can try https://www.instagram.com they’re total Coolaiders)
2. Open Chrome Developer Tools on Sources tab (control+shift+i or command+shift+i)

   1. Dev tools open on the Sources tab
3. In the very right of the top menu bar, click the vertical ellipsis and select **search all files**
4. In he search box down on left type **FIRED** in capital letters, clear the checkbox **Ignore case**, type **Enter**

   1. One or more matches appear below. The version is an export very close to the search string looking like **version: "16.0.0"**
5. If the version number is not immediately visible: double click a line that begins with a line number

   1. ECMAScript appears in the middle pane
6. If the version number is not immediately visible: click the two braces at bottom left of the ECMAScript pane **{}**

   1. ECMAScript is reformatted and easier to read
7. If the version number is not immediately visible: scroll up and down a few lines to find it or try another search key

   1. If the code is not minified, search for **ReactVersion**
      There should be 2 hits with the same value
   2. If the code is minified, search for either **SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED** or **react-dom**
   3. Or search for the likely version string itself: **"15.** or **"16.** or even **"0.15**

**Method 2: Use a DOM breakpoint:**

1. Load the page rendered by React
2. Right click a React element (anything, like an input field or a box) and select `Inspect Element`

   1. Chrome Developer Tools displays the `Elements` pane
3. As high up in the tree as possible from the selected element, but no higher than the React root element (often a div directly inside body with id root: **<div id="root">**), right click an element and select `Break On… - subtree modifications`

   1. Note: It is possible to compare contents of the Elements tab (DOM current state) with the response for the same resouce on the Networks tab. This may reveal React’s root element
4. Reload the page by clicking Reload left of the address bar

   1. Chrome Developer Tools stops at the breakpoint and displays the `Sources` pane
5. In the rightmost pane, examine the `Call Stack` sub-pane
6. As far down the call stack as possible, there should be a `render` entry, this is `ReactDOM.render`
7. Click the line below `render`, ie. the code that invokes render
8. The middle pane now displays ECMAScript with an expression containing ***.render*** highlighted
9. Hover the mouse cursor over the object used to invoke render, is. the `react-dom` module exports object

   1. if the code line goes: **Object(u.render)(…**, hover over the **u**
10. A tooltip window is displayed containing `version: "15.6.2"`, ie. all values exported by `react-dom`

The version is also injected into React dev tools, but as far as I know not displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 16):

First Install React dev tools if not installed and then use the run below code in the browser console :

```
__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.get(1).version
```

Answer (score 11):

In an existing project a simple way to see the React version is to go to a `render` method of any component and add:

`<p>{React.version}</p>`

This assumes you import React like this: `import React from 'react'`

Comment: Simple and easy.

Answer (score 8):

You can either run the following command(s) on your terminal, depending if you are using npm or yarn:

```
npm view react version
or
yarn view react version
```

Or You can also open your package.json file in your project under the "dependencies" check "react": after the semicolon will be the version of your react

Comment: `npm view react version` shows latest package version, not the version installed. And `package.json` typically won't specify a specific React version, but rather a minimal required version, which is not sufficient to identify the running version.

Answer (score 7):

Open the console, then run `window.React.version`.

This worked for me in Safari and Chrome while upgrading from 0.12.2 to 16.2.0.

Comment: window.React is undefined.

Comment: worked for me in Chrome 96, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

For an app created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) I managed to see the version:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools / Firefox Dev Tools,
2. Search and open main.XXXXXXXX.js file where XXXXXXXX is a builds hash /could be different,
3. Optional: format source by clicking on the {} to show the formatted source,
4. Search as text inside the source for react-dom,
5. in Chrome was found: "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
6. in Firefox was found: 'react-dom': '^16.4.0'

The app was deployed without source map.

Answer (score 4):

In index.js file, simply replace **App** component with "React.version".
E.g.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.version, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have checked this with React v16.8.1

Answer (score 1):

**Use the command line commands for checking the version of the ReactJS. You can run the below command.**

```
npm view react version
          or
yarn view react version
```

Answer (score 0):

This strategy should work all of the time: In the end React has to be included in a js file in the html through a script tag. So find that file and look for the React version.

1. Look through all the scripts included in the HTML (view source)
2. One of the links include the script to React. WebPack lumps the libraries together under a common-xxxx.js file
3. Open that script file and ctrl + f search for React
4. Presto, version number there

Answer (score 0):

If you have already deployed your app which used webpack. You can use the below step to identify the "react" and "react-dom".

1. Open DeveloperTool in your browser
2. Go to Source Tab
3. Check your `appName`.js file
4. Search for "react" or "react-dom"
   You will find something like below. That will be the version your react-app is using.

> "webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/react?1aa9": () => (loadStrictVersionCheckFallback("default", "react", [,[1,17,0,0],[1,16,8,0],1],// ..SOMETHINNG

> "webpack/sharing/consume/default/react-dom/react-dom?8d07": () => (loadStrictVersionCheckFallback("default", "react-dom", [,[1,17,0,0],[1,16,8,0],1], // ..SOMETHINNG

OR

> register("react-dom", "17.0.2", () // ..SOMETHING

> register("react", "17.0.2", ()// ..SOMETHINNG

*Note: It only applicable for deployed app*

Answer (score -1):

`console.log(React.version)` will print the version of the react running in your project.

Answer (score -2):

To know the react version, Open package.json file in root folder, search the keywork react. You will see like "react": "^16.4.0",

Comment: The question was how can you tell the React version in the browser.