# "module not found : Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactMount' "

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I used Reactjs and webpack to start a project, and when I run the "node server" in the command prompt, there is an error like this:

[image]

And the chrome explorer opened successful but also have problems as follows:

[image]

The github is: (github.com/Yangqin0607/gallery)

Here is the package.json

```
    {
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "YOUR DESCRIPTION - Generated by generator-react-webpack",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
    "copy": "copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./src/favicon.ico ./dist",
    "dist": "npm run copy & webpack --env=dist",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "posttest": "npm run lint",
    "release:major": "npm version major && npm publish && git push --follow-tags",
    "release:minor": "npm version minor && npm publish && git push --follow-tags",
    "release:patch": "npm version patch && npm publish && git push --follow-tags",
    "serve": "node server.js --env=dev",
    "serve:dist": "node server.js --env=dist",
    "start": "node server.js --env=dev",
    "test": "karma start",
    "test:watch": "karma start --autoWatch=true --singleRun=false"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Your name here",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "chai": "^3.2.0",
    "copyfiles": "^1.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eslint": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.0",
    "isparta-instrumenter-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mocha": "^3.0.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.0.0",
    "normalize.css": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^15.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: It goes without saying, are you sure `G:\toolsForFE\gallery\node_modules\react\lib\ReactMount` exists?

Comment: There's no ReactMout in react\lib, but I don't know how to get a ReactMout. I try to run the command "npm install ReactMount", but failed. By the way, I just run the command "npm install generator-react-webpack" and "yo react-webpack gallery", after this I run the "node server" to open the server, then something's wrong here but I haven't modify anything.

Comment: which version of React are you using? Import from `react/lib/` has never been supported and with React 15.4 (released yesterday) there was a refactor that moved stuff around in that directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This issue is related to the `react-hot-loader` package. You are using an old version that relies on the `ReactMount.js` file being present in the `node_modules/react/lib` folder.

There is no easy one way fix for that but you have a few options which are:

1. Try to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/v3.0.0-beta.6/docs/README.md#usage-with-external-react (but I have been unlucky so far)
2. Remove the hot reloader for react (in your `webpack.config` remove the `'react-hot'` loader)
3. Update the `react-hot-loader` package to version 3 (here is how to do so: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/commit/64f58b7010a1b2a71ad16716eb37ac1031f93915). But note that this package has been in alpha for a while now...
4. Rollback your react version to one that includes the `ReactMount.js` in the lib folder (15.0.1 used to have this file not sure when it stopped).

**Update:** React Hot Loader 3 is now in beta with a more comprehensive upgrade guide: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/v3.0.0-beta.7/docs#migration-to-30

Answer (score 8):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
Spent the rest of the day in a rabbit hole of github issues/comments, weighing the pros/cons/feasibility of various hacky workarounds.

The quickest, simplest, "I just want to work on the original problem I intended to work on today" fix that worked for me comes from: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/417#issuecomment-261548082

In your webpack config, add the following alias to the `resolve` section:

```
resolve: {
  alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' }
}
```

This is *not* a stable long term fix, this is a development only fix so you can continue developing without being forced to deal with upgrade issues out of the blue.

I'm still not 100% sure why I'm seeing this problem in my one app and not another, both were generated from `fountain.js` react-redux generator and have identical `package.json`.

Comment: Thanks you saved me few hours. I am having exact same problem, this temporary fix worked for me.

Comment: Just don't forget the "temporary" part! :)

Comment: One you deploy, it won't matter correct? I'm not understanding why you keep saying this is a "temporary" fix... there is nothing else to be done.

Answer (score 6):

You are using an outdated `react-hot-loader` package that uses the internal react api throught `react\lib\ReactMount`. Now react doesn't allow this hence the problem.

Try updating it to the latest version:

```
$ npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader@latest
```

Comment: Now my error is that this other file is missing: ./node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js

Comment: Ha ha!  Fixed with 'sudo npm remove --save webpack' and 'sudo npm install webpack@3.11.0 --save', thanks though!

Comment: did this. Nothing happened. Same problem. unbelievable

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for all your answers. I have solved my problems.

> " This issue is related to the react-hot-loader package. You are using an old version that relies on the ReactMount.js file being present in the node_modules/react/lib folder." said by cheesemacfly.

So here is the solution for me:
1) updating the react-hot-loader to the latest version

```
npm install --save-dev react-hot-loader@latest
```

but here is another problem linked with react-hot-loader
[image]

2) so I removed the react-hot-loader from 'cfg/dev.js'
change the code

```
loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader'
```

into

```
loader: 'babel-loader'
```

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to cheesemacfly, I was able to solve the same issue with your suggestion to remove 'react-hot' from the loader.

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
    exclude: /(node_modules|lib\/ckeditor)/
}
```

I Changed to:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /(node_modules|lib\/ckeditor)/
}
```

Remember to change the word 'loaders' to 'loader' since you are no longer referencing a list.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably just a dependency issue. It's either not getting the correct version of react or not installing it correctly.

```
# update npm
$ npm install -g npm

# reinstall the generator-react-webpack package (note the global tags)
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-react-webpack
```

Then attempt to generate your app.

Comment: I have updated the npm, and reinstall the generator-react-webpack as you  suggested. And the problem is still there.

Comment: Can you post what your `package.json` file looks like?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and none of the solution worked. It then occurred to me that it seems that react is missing. I got the problem after I installed and uninstalled a package for postgreSQL.

So I added it. PS, I was using yarn

```
yarn add react
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating `react-hot-loader` didn't work for me, but removing the `react-hot` form the loaders list, by simply commenting it, fixed the issue:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loaders: [
        // 'react-hot',
       'babel'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play:

1. Properly upgrading all your dependencies, and,
2. Use `webpack v. 3.11.0`, DO NOT upgrade to `webpack v. 4.00`,
3. Downgrade ReactJS to `React v. 15.6.2`.

Open `package.json`, which will have a list of things like...

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.10",
  "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  (etc.)
```

Then run a command like this in your package base directory, which has the same dependencies as listed above...

```
sudo npm install --save react@15.6.2 react-dom@15.6.2 react-scripts@latest webpack@3.11.0 jquery@latest jquery-ui@latest
```

***TLDR ANSWER :*** ^^^ This is the one command you'll actually need to run.

Notice the webpack-specific version.

After this, *everything* worked for me!  I I checked the ReactJS version , using this answer , https://stackoverflow.com/a/36994601/2430549 , and my package.json now looks like...

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
  "react": "^16.4.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
  "react-hot-loader": "^4.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
```

Source: Answer by JanTheHun, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9793

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an old version of **react-dom**.

I changed versions of **react** and **react-dom** to 16.X (to be exact : "react": "16.13.1", "react-dom": "16.13.1",), and then this problem went away for me.