# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in 'C:\Users\name\ecom\node_modules\react-dom\lib'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was working on a react project and suddenly this error occurred saying,

---

*Failed to compile
**../node_modules/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/lib/React' in 'C:\Users\Angelin\ecom\node_modules\react-dom\lib'***

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "antd": "^4.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.5",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
     "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.25.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multiscroll-reactjs": "^1.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "react-awesome-button": "^6.5.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
    "react-image-file-resizer": "^0.4.2",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.13",
    "react-star-ratings": "^2.3.0",
    "slugify": "^1.4.6",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.17.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of installation of packages at first glance.

You can try removing `node_modules` folder and install all packages again with `npm install` or `yarn install`.

If this does not work then you can refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652327/module-not-found-error-cannot-resolve-module-react-lib-reactmount/40661900)