# How to tell the background architecture of a web page from source code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, architecture, frameworks

How can I tell what is the background of a website *by looking at the source code* of the page?

Like, what is the architecture, which web framework was used and similar?

For example, is it PHP or Node.js on the server-side? Was it developed in ASP.NET? Which JS framework is it using?

**EDIT:**

Found this for [React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994564/how-can-one-tell-the-version-of-react-running-at-runtime-in-the-browser).

And this for [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950213/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-web-app-was-built-using-angular).

Comment: You can know it's php if it's not truncated from the url, or if you watch if the network requests are going to `somepage.php`.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way of seeing all the relevant info about the framework by looking at (for example) some source code headers?

Comment: You can check web framework by specific data in the header in a request. However, it is easy to hide. You can know it only some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not reliably get this information.  You can, as Mirakurun said, make some guesses by looking at form actions, or URLs that appear in source-code, but it is not reliable, and you certainly won't know exactly what framework is on the back-end.

This is partially on purpose, as leaking specific framework information would allow attackers to target specific vulnerabilities.