# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.useState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Below I provide a simplified sketch of my ReactJS code (based on [material-ui](https://material-ui.com)). This code does not compile, because probably I added `function handleClickOpen()` and `function handleClose()` in a wrong place.
How can I fix it?

In particular, the following is the error message:

> TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default.a.useState is
>   not a function

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';


const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});


class BottomControls extends Component {
    render() {

        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

        function handleClickOpen() {
          setOpen(true);
        }

        function handleClose() {
          setOpen(false);
        }

        return (
          <Fragment>
             # ...
          </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default BottomControls;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Hooks like `useState` are only for functional components
2. They should be called outside of the render function
3. React and react-dom need to be version 16.8 or higher

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import Slide from '@material-ui/core/Slide';


const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
  return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});


function BottomControls(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  function handleClickOpen() { setOpen(true); }
  function handleClose() { setOpen(false); }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      // whatever
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default BottomControls;
```

Comment: I tried to change `BottomControls` to `function` as you suggested. Still get the same error.

Comment: Well, did you check your versions of `react` and `react-dom` are 16.8 or higher?

Comment: How can I do it? I tried to run `npm ls react-dom -g`. It returned: `/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)`

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994564/how-can-one-tell-the-version-of-react-running-at-runtime-in-the-browser

Comment: I checked the version. It's 16.7.0. How should I update it? Is there any solution for `16.7.0`?

Comment: If you use `npm`, update your package.json `"react": "16.8"` and `"react-dom": "16.8"`

Comment: Ok, I updated React to 16.8. Now I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` in these piece of code that worked well bofore: `return (<Fragment><CssBaseline /><AppBar position="fixed" color="primary" className={this.props.styles.appBar}>`. I use your approach.

Comment: Everywhere you used to call `this.props`, it should now be `props`, the argument of the functional component (see edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

As per React documentation, we cannot use hooks inside class based components refer below url
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html